# Navigation buttons using <form> won't display in center

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cannot make the navigation buttons display in their full width. I tried to give the  element a width of 100%, 989px (which is 100%) or less than that, only resulting in the buttons to then display underneath each other on the left hand side.
Thanks for your help :)

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.button {
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffda;
  border-color: #ffffda;
  text-decoration-color: #49156e;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <form class="nav" action="index.html"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Home"></form>
  <form class="nav" action="tours.html"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Tours"></form>
  <form class="nav" action="guides.html"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Guides"></form>
  <form class="nav" action="contactUs.html"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Contact Us"></form>
</nav>
```

**The result**

[image]

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNvyPY

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just figured it out!!

The width of my .button related to the width of the .nav and as I only gave it 15% it only displayed 15% of how wide the form was. I have now set the width of the button to 150px and it looks just the way it needs to look :)

```
.button  {
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #ffffda;
border-color: #ffffda;
text-decoration-color: #49156e;
}
```

Cheers guys!!